# Condense Array to Number

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to solve a problem for my homework but im stuck.

Here is the task:

> Write a program to read an array of integers and condense them by summing adjacent couples of elements until a single integer is obtained. For example, if we have 3 elements {2, 10, 3}, we sum the first two and the second two elements and obtain {2+10, 10+3} = {12, 13}, then we sum again all adjacent elements and obtain {12+13} = {25}.

This is what i've done so far but im stuck and don't know how to continue.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(input[i]);
}

int sum = 0;
int[] condensed = new int [arr.length-1];
System.out.println(condensed.length);

while (condensed.length > 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < condensed.length; i++) {
        condensed[i] = arr[i] + arr[i+1];
    }   
}

if (condensed.length == 1) {
    sum = condensed[0] + condensed[1];
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

The input is "5 0 4 1 2" and the output should be "35" but I get "4".

Comment: It surprises me that your code actually completed. That while loop on condensed.length should never terminate! So please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. And please fix the broken formatting too!

Comment: I'm sorry for that. It's my first question.

Comment: the *result*  you are getting is from `System.out.println(condensed.length)` and the rest never ends (as already explained by GhostCat)

Comment: For `{2, 10, 3}`, the answer is `25 = 1*2 + 2*10 + 1*3`; for `{5, 0, 4, 1, 2}`, the answer is `35 = 1*5 + 4*0 + 6*4 + 4*1 + 1*2`. Does this suggest a method to calculate the result?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you already have your array (`int arr[]`) or numbers converter from the input, you can contiuously loop through the array from the first element to the one before the last adding that value to the next value and storing them in a temporary array.

You will then replace the value array with the temp array and continue the process until the length of the array is equal to one.

```
while (arr.length > 1) {
    int temp[] = new int[arr.length - 1];  

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        temp[i] = arr[i] + arr[i + 1];
    }

    arr = temp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for editing my question above. This works and I can understand why and also why it didn't work with my code!

Answer (score 0):

i've wrote an example code that you can expand if you have troubles let me know:

```
        int[] a1 = new int[] {2, 10 , 3};
        int[] a2 = new int[2];
        int[] a3 = new int[1];

        for(int i = 0; i < a1.length - 1; i++)
            a2[i] = a1[i] + a1[i + 1];

        for(int i = 0; i < a2.length - 1; i++)
            a3[i] = a2[i] + a2[i + 1];

        System.out.println(a3[0]);
```

in general you whould generate N int arrays (N = arr.length - 1) and fill them with a loop

Comment: what if entry consisst of 4 (or more) elements?

Comment: i've supposed to expand the code that i've provided as i wrote but if needed i can modify it using Lists but i think is too much